# I cant make my java code wait for a routine to finish to start another (equal routine)

Tags: java, for-loop, countdown

I want to create a Java program that allows me to repeat a sequence of  - 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 FIRE - the number of times i want.
I started by searching how can i create a countdown, and i use a timer schedule so  i can set the JTextFields text every 1 second ( to produce the effect of a normal countdown). But the problem is that when i want to repeat, lest say, 2 times this  countdown, my java code is starting both countdowns at the same time and not waiting for the first one to finish. My main goal is to click a button and start a certain number of countdowns. The number of countdowns to produce is inputed in the enabled JTextField.

I leave my entire code here:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import javax.swing.*;



public class Counter {

    public static class MyThread implements Runnable {
        private JTextField tx1;
        private JTextField tx2;
        CountDownLatch latch;

        int count;

        public MyThread (JTextField tx1,JTextField tx2,CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.tx1=tx1;
            this.tx2=tx2;
            this.latch = latch;
          }

        public void run() {
                 tx1.setText("");
                    tx2.setText("");
                    count=5;
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        int counter=0;
                          public void run() {
                             tx1.setText("");
                            tx1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                            System.out.println("!");
                            count--;
                            counter++;
                            if (counter==6){
                                tx2.setText("FIRE");
                                this.cancel();
                            }
                          }
                        }, 1000,1000);
                        latch.countDown();

          } 
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Counter");
    JPanel panel=new JPanel ();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    JButton bt1=new JButton("Start");
    JButton bt2=new JButton("Reset");
    JLabel lb1=new JLabel ("Puffs");
    final JTextField tx1= new JTextField(5);
    final JTextField tx2= new JTextField(10);
    final JTextField tx3= new JTextField(5);
    tx1.setEnabled(false);
    tx2.setEnabled(false);
    panel.add(tx1);
    panel.add(tx2);
    panel.add(lb1);
    panel.add(tx3);
    panel.add(bt1);
    panel.add(bt2);
    frame.add(panel);

    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

    new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2,latch)).start();
    new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2,latch)).start();
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
//          int tr=Integer.parseInt(tx3.getText());

        }   
    });

    bt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {


            }

    });

    ////
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
    Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();

    Dimension size = frame.getPreferredSize();
    frame.setLocation((int) ((bounds.width / 2) - (size.getWidth() / 2)), 
            (int) ((bounds.height / 2) - (size.getHeight() / 2)));

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
     }
  }
```

Sorry about bad formatting and bad writting.
Much appreciated by your help!

Edited CODE

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import javax.swing.*;



public class Counter {

    public static class MyThread implements Runnable {
        private JTextField tx1;
        private JTextField tx2;

        int count;

        public MyThread (JTextField tx1,JTextField tx2) {
            this.tx1=tx1;
            this.tx2=tx2;
          }

        public void run() {
                 tx1.setText("");
                    tx2.setText("");
                    count=5;
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        int counter=0;
                          public void run() {
                             tx1.setText("");
                            tx1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                            System.out.println("!");
                            count--;
                            counter++;
                            if (counter==6){
                                tx2.setText("FIRE");
                                this.cancel();
                            }
                          }
                        }, 1000,1000);

          } 
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Counter");
    JPanel panel=new JPanel ();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
    JButton bt1=new JButton("Start");
    JButton bt2=new JButton("Reset");
    JLabel lb1=new JLabel ("Puffs");
    final JTextField tx1= new JTextField(5);
    final JTextField tx2= new JTextField(10);
    final JTextField tx3= new JTextField(5);
    tx1.setEnabled(false);
    tx2.setEnabled(false);
    panel.add(tx1);
    panel.add(tx2);
    panel.add(lb1);
    panel.add(tx3);
    panel.add(bt1);
    panel.add(bt2);
    frame.add(panel);

    bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
//          int tr=Integer.parseInt(tx3.getText());
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2));
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2));
            t1.start();
            try {
                t1.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            t2.start();
            try {
                t2.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }   
    });

    bt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
            }

    });

    ////
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
    Rectangle bounds = gc.getBounds();
    Dimension size = frame.getPreferredSize();
    frame.setLocation((int) ((bounds.width / 2) - (size.getWidth() / 2)), 
            (int) ((bounds.height / 2) - (size.getHeight() / 2)));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this will just starts both the `Timer` simultaneously.By using this code.

```
 CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

    new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2,latch)).start();
    new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2,latch)).start();
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But you can make the second timer to be executed after the first timer finishes.
Just put this after the first timer finishes.

```
new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2,latch)).start();
```

Comment: I changed the code, trying to use the .join()but still not working. And with the changing you sugested, the code gets stuck and doesnt change the text in the JTextField.

Comment: Please update ur chngd code.I will find the problems in that.

Comment: I cannot put all the code, its to much characters.., can i send it to you by private message?

Comment: Dude its not like that.Your need is to run the second timer after only the first timer finishes.Is'nt it.

Comment: Ok i updated the code in the original post, below the Edit CODE line.

Comment: I have just posted my new answer.Just have a look of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you launch timers in different Threads, they will naturally be executed simulatenously: this is the purpose of Threads.

If you want to synchronize them, for example, launch one thread when the previous one finishes, you can use the `join()` function, which will "pause" your code until the thread is finished.

```java
Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2, latch));
Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyThread(tx1, tx2, latch));
t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
t2.join();
// ...
```

Thus, t2 is started only after t1 finishes.
You can apply this to a for loop, in which you keep track of the previous thread, and start the next one after oldThread.join().

Hope it could help you !

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i already tried to do that way, but still the join action is not working and not waiting for the first thread..

Answer (score 0):

Hey at last i have find out the defect in your code.The first code(Not the Edited one) you have posted is the correct one and the correct way of using the `CountDownLatch`(used for Synchronisation).
I have just altered your `MyThread` class 's `run()` method.Just have a look of it.

```
public static class MyThread implements Runnable {
        private JTextField tx1;
        private JTextField tx2;
        CountDownLatch latch;

        int count;

        public MyThread (JTextField tx1,JTextField tx2,CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.tx1=tx1;
            this.tx2=tx2;
            this.latch = latch;
          }

        public void run() {
                 tx1.setText("");
                    tx2.setText("");
                    count=5;
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                        int counter=0;
                          public void run() {
                             tx1.setText("");
                            tx1.setText(Integer.toString(count));
                            System.out.println("!");
                            count--;
                            counter++;
                            if (counter==6){
                                tx2.setText("FIRE");
 latch.countDown();
                                this.cancel();
                            }
                          }
                        }, 1000,1000);
                        //latch.countDown();Detailed Explaination is below.

          } 
    }
```

The `latch.countDown()` is directly executed when first `Thread` started.So you want to put it in the `if` condition.So that the second `Thread` will wait for the first `Thread` to be finished.
`latch.countDown()` method is like a gateway opener.When this function is called,the countdown in the `CountDownLatch` will be decremented by 1.So that the next `Thread` in the `CountDownLatch` will be executed.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, and i think its working a little better now, but i now that the problem that the JTextField is not showing the countdown number every second.

Comment: Did ur textbox visible to u

Comment: Y sure, it is visible, i just dont understand, its like when i tried to use thread.sleep(), the UI is frozen :P

Comment: If u can type or click inthe textfield

Comment: I i can, you just have to enable it, but that is not the problem i think. I thought there would be an easier way to make a repeatable counter :P

Comment: Do you tried printing the count variable.What does it shows

Comment: When i print the coundown it shows exactly what i wanted in the jtextfield, but the jtextfield text is not being changed during the countdown....

Comment: K then try it out.Just remove txt1.setText(""); and change this to tx1.setText(Integer.toString(count)); to tx1.setText(""+count);